# Get language of Instagram post through API?

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

I am using the following URL to scrape the popular images/videos from Instagram (using PHP).

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=CLIENT-ID
```

It returns a json object, but I do not see a value for "language". This is a problem because sometimes the captains are in arabic or something else and I need them to be English for my web app. Is there anyway to know the language of the post or will I have to use some language detecting function?

Comment: Care telling me why my question got downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [this](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_LanguageDetect) for the source code, and [this](http://languagedetect.org/) for a demo. You then just have to pass the captions in to detect the language. It checks for 52 languages. You can also use Google Translate's API.

Comment: Thanks, it would be much easier if Instagram recorded the language of it's users like they do with Facebook. This tool is not always accurate, especially with short strings.

Comment: Yea, but hey, you can always write your own function! ;)